# How to add a row after determining the values of the cells above are the same in VBA for Excel

Tags: excel, vba, increment

Im am trying to write a macro that ascending sorts items in a row and then adds a row between matching items.

basically I am looking for something like this

```
a
a
a
>>new row inserted here because there are no more instances of "a"<<
b
b
```

I am envisioning that I will need two variables, `cellOne` and `cellTwo` which will hold the values of, for example, cells A1 and A2 respectively. As the loop runs the values of `cellOne` and `cellTwo` will increment so that each cell in the column is compared to the cell above to determine if they match. The part that I am having trouble with is figuring out how I would write a for loop that iterates through the column and increments the values of my variables so that the value of variable `cellOne` for example increments from A1 to A2 and so on while at the same time `cellTwo` increments from A2 to A3.

There may be an easier way to do what I am describing. In a nut shell all I am looking to do is to find a way to insert a new line after any given number of cells in a sorted column match before continuing on to repeat this process for however many more ranges of matching cells there might be in a column.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Honestly I don't even know where to begin on this. I am brand new to VBA and its syntax is very confusing from my level of understanding or lack there of. Right now I'm just working with record macro and some basic tutorials to figure out what to do. I'm not sure how to write a for loop in VBA so that I could increment the cell values contained in my two variables based on my i counter

Comment: Store your first value, check your next Cell, if it is different, insert row or insert Cell and change your store value and so on until your next Cell is blank